# Mimicking Multiproject Execution In Composite Included Build with Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, composite, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am simplifying the setup I have to illustrate my issue, but have included structural complexities.

Using Gradle's Kotlin DSL I have a composite build where the root project is empty and the two included builds are both side-by-side multiproject builds with varying structures that make use of "container" projects (aka, empty directories with no build.gradle.kts files) for organization purposes.

```
.
├── app
│   ├── common
│   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── js
│   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── jvm
│   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── settings.gradle.kts
├── library
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── common
│   │   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   │   └── jvm
│   │       └── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── other-component
│   │   ├── common
│   │   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   │   └── jvm
│   │       └── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── util
│   │   ├── util1
│   │   │   ├── common
│   │   │   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   │   │   ├── js
│   │   │   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   │   │   └── jvm
│   │   │       └── build.gradle.kts
│   │   └── util2
│   │       ├── common
│   │       │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   │       ├── js
│   │       │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   │       └── jvm
│   │           └── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── settings.gradle.kts
├── build.gradle.kts
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

My desire is to be able to run build in the root composite project within the IDE (Intellij) and it mimic the behavior of a multiproject execution, where everything underneath that project executes the task in turn.

In Groovy, one can just use the spread operator on includedBuilds*.tasks* in the composite project to wire it up, but in the Kotlin DSL, we only have access to task, which is a single TaskReference and no way to get a collection of Tasks (TaskCollection or Collection of Tasks) or collection of TaskReferences.

So in the rootProject of the composite build.gradle.kts, I have:

```
tasks {
    val clean by getting {
        gradle.includedBuilds.forEach { this.dependsOn(it.task(":cleanAll")) }
    }

    val build by getting {
        gradle.includedBuilds.forEach { this.dependsOn(it.task(":buildAll")) }
    }
}
```

Then in one of the included builds build.gradle.kts files, I have tried wiring them two different ways (well many but these are the two approaches):

```
// Variation 1
tasks {
    val buildAll : GradleBuild by creating {
        this.dependsOn(tasks.getByPath(":build"))
    }

    val cleanAll : Delete by creating {
        this.dependsOn(tasks.getByPath(":clean"))
    }
}

// Variation 2
tasks {
    val buildAll: GradleBuild by creating {
        subprojects.forEach {
            this.dependsOn(it.tasks.getByPath(":build"))
        }
    }

    val cleanAll: Delete by creating {
        subprojects.forEach {
            this.dependsOn(it.tasks.getByPath(":clean"))
        }
    }
}

// Variation 2.b
tasks {
    val buildAll: GradleBuild by creating {
        this.dependsOn(subprojects.mapNotNull(it.tasks.getByPath(":build")))
    }

    val cleanAll: Delete by creating {
        this.dependsOn(subprojects.mapNotNull(it.tasks.getByPath(":clean")))
    }
}

// I even used different ways to try and get the tasks such as it.tasks["root:library:build"], it.tasks[":library:build"], and it.tasks["library:build"] since I know that the included builds are executed in an isolated fashion.  None of these worked
// The result was when I used absolute paths, gradle spat back that these tasks didn't exist (I assumed because they were lifecycle tasks).
```

Basically, trying the variations above only ever built and cleaned the rootProjects of the included builds and never the subprojects.  Is this a bug?

I do not want to have to resort to needing knowledge of the underlying structure of the included builds to wire this up.  That would be unsustainable.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I realized that I might be referencing lifecycle tasks that don't exist in this way?  (I'm not sure how to check that).  In order to rule that out, I went ahead and created a task for every subproject in the subprojects{} block of each included build.  I subsequently made the rootproject build/cleanall tasks then depend on all of the subproject tasks respectively.

Comment: Then it gave me a circular dependency issue citing the :rootIncluded:build circularly depends on :rootIncluded:build.  When I tried to use absolute paths in getByPath, it told me that the projects don't exist (and shows that it is looking it up relatively).

It's almost when getting the task by path originally it will /only/ accept relative paths (I tried all the ways I could think of in case it was user error), and then when validating or using it to look up in the dependsOn it actually does it all from the rootProject of the included build.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the following code to achieve this. First, create a `settings.gradle.kts` in the root that programmatically searches for builds for include:

```
rootDir.walk().filter {
    it != rootDir && !it.name.startsWith(".") && it.resolve("build.gradle.kts").isFile
}.forEach(::includeBuild)
```

Then create a `build.gradle.kts` file in the root that "forwards" all root task invocations of the form `all<TASK>` to `<INCLUDED_BUILD>:<TASK>`:

```
tasks.addRule("Pattern: all<TASK>") {
    val taskName = this
    val taskPrefix = "all"

    if (startsWith(taskPrefix)) {
        task(taskName) {
            gradle.includedBuilds.forEach { build ->
                val buildTaskName = taskName.removePrefix(taskPrefix).decapitalize()
                dependsOn(build.task(":$buildTaskName"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, running `./gradlew allAssemble` on the root project will effectively execute the `assemble` task on all included builds.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not sure what was going on and why those other methods didn't work, but I found a method that works and does not require me to manufacture synthetic tasks that depend on the lifecycle tasks.

Composite rootproject build.gradle.kts tasks remain the same as stated in the original question:

```
tasks {
    val clean by getting {
        gradle.includedBuilds.forEach { this.dependsOn(it.task(":cleanAll")) }
    }

    val build by getting {
        gradle.includedBuilds.forEach { this.dependsOn(it.task(":buildAll")) }
    }
}
```

Tasks declaration in included build root projects' build.gradle.kts-es need to collect and depend on tasks in the following way:

```
tasks {
    val buildAll: GradleBuild by creating {
        dependsOn(getTasksByName("build", true))
    }

    val cleanAll: Delete by creating {
        dependsOn(getTasksByName("clean", true))
    }
}
```

This will recursively gather the tasks.  Although my previous techniques of iterating through all of the subprojects should have also done the trick since subprojects contains all subprojects, for some reason it wasn't working.  This is though!  Hopefully this helps out other people.